# can we specify multiple foldmarkers in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to fold multiple lines in vim with `:set foldmethod=marker` I have done `:set foldmarker={,}` is there any way such that we can fold function that has starting braces='[' and end braces=']' and also fold a function with starting braces='{' and end braces='}' like in vscode we can fold any function with any starting and ending braces.

Answer (score 1):

From `:help folding`:

```
There are six methods to select folds:
    manual      manually define folds
    indent      more indent means a higher fold level
    expr        specify an expression to define folds
    syntax      folds defined by syntax highlighting
    diff        folds for unchanged text
    marker      folds defined by markers in the text
```

- `marker` won't help for the reason given under `:help 'foldmarker'`:

  ```
  The marker is a literal string (a regular expression would be too slow).
  ```

  See `:help fold-marker`.
- `diff` is irrelevant.

  See `:help fold-diff`.
- `syntax` may help, depending on the language and how the syntax script for that language was written.

  See `:help fold-syntax`.
- `expr` is the most powerful method because it lets *you* decide exactly what to fold and how to fold it.

  It is also the hardest to set up, for obvious reasons. See `:help fold-expr`.
- `indent` is a pretty dumb method, which makes it very memory efficient and versatile. You could try that one because it doesn't care about braces at all.

  See `:help fold-indent`.
- And then there is the `manual` method, which lets you define folds with motions.

  This lets you do things like `zfi{` or `zf12j`.

  See `:help fold-manual`.

Comment: I am using flutter dart and for that indent can't be used and manual takes very much time for large project and the fold-syntax folds only the {,} brackets so it does not do much thing.

Comment: Looking at [this hello world](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab) I would say that `indent` seems perfectly adapted.